# How does one compute estimate of $ \theta$ for this density function?

Tags: statistics

Currently, I am studying for my exam in Statistics. We use Rice's book, so I am trying to do some of the exercises in this book. One of the exercises is as follows:

> Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d. with density function $ f(x \mid \theta) = e^{ - (x - \theta) } $, when $x \geq \theta $ , and $f(x \mid \theta ) = 0$ otherwise. Find the method of moments estimate of $\theta$.

I know that, in order to compute the method of moments estimate of $\theta$, one has to equate the theoretical average $ \bar{X} $ with the expectation. I don't know how to compute the expectation, though. I was thinking of finding it with a double integral:

$$\mathbb E[f(x\mid\theta)] = \int_{0}^{\infty}\!\int_{\theta}^{\infty} e^{ - (x - \theta ) }\,dx\,d\theta,$$ and then doing something similar in the region left of the y-axis. This, however, did not lead to the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this, if you are familiar with common distributions, is to recognize that the density function you were given is *almost* the density of an Exponential(1) random variable--to be more precise, $X-\theta$ follows an Exponential(1) distribution. So $\mathbb E[ X-\theta] = 1$ (the expectation of an Exponential(1) distribution), and thus $\mathbb E[X] = 1+\theta$, the same result akkkk obtained--but without having to do integration by parts!

Answer (score 0):

$\theta$ is just a parameter.

$$ \mathbb{E}_\theta[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x|\theta) dx=\int_{\theta}^{\infty} x e^{ - (x - \theta ) } dx\overset{\text{integration by parts}}{=}1+\theta$$

Comment: What does p.i. stand for?